# What is templating/template engine

Tags: node.js

I did a course on full-stack on web and afterwards I applied for internship.

In the internship the interviewer asked me a question related to templating engine in NodeJS and the terms sounded totally alien to me.

So I came home and was only able to figure out npm modules like moustache..

So can someone explain me what is templating/template engine in NodeJS.

Comment: The general concept is pretty decently explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_processor

Comment: It's the commonly used name for a tool that compile variables in a rendered view, often html, generaly used in web applications (ex. ejs, handlebars, jade...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Templating Engines are to split code for example you got a web application you can split the `footer, header, body, layout` and more to use it on other pages.

You can also use the templating engines to connect them to your modules and functions for example:

- You can have a button in `ejs` or `pug` and if you click it you can run an acction from your app.js. I personally use templating engines with combination of frameworks like [express.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express).

**In the next interview you can say:**

- Templating engines in nodejs can be used to split the nodejs application code from the frontend layout and the frontend elements can be used dynamically with the node application for example if you click a button it can run a action from your node `app.js`. This can be used for any type of application and it can have user input interactions like a form field that the user can fill up and that the input gets saved to a database like MongoDB. With the templating engine, you can have the frontend interact with the nodejs application.
- Templating engines are also used to split elements into multiple components like:
  `footer, header, head, layout` and more. So you don't need to rewrite those elements for other pages and that way your application can scale easily.
- Templating engines are mostly used in combination with nodejs frameworks like [express.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) for example.

I can also recommend you [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application) it's a good explanation of templating in nodejs using `ejs` and `express.js`. They are way more templating engines but `ejs` is widely used and very popular so I would recommend learning this first.

In Nodejs the most used templating engines are [pug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug) and [ejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs)

Please let me know if you got question and I really hope I could help you.

greetings,

Karim

Comment: I am aware about `ejs` but we then use `react` where we break our code in component and container. So can we call react a `Templating engine`

Comment: React is a JavaScript library for building user interfaces. 

But it works like a templating engine. Except that it has the server side js code and html layout structure in the js files splitting as react modules. I would call react a server side templating engine.

Answer (score 2):

Simply said 'Templating' engine is an engine that can manipulate your HTML code from the server side using the server side code you use. By it's very authentic built in syntaxes you can loop, change content dynamically, alert messages to user and etc.

there are tons of templating engines out there

- Laravel - blade templating engine
- ASP.NET - Razor blade templating engine
- Node.js - handlebars, Pug and few others